# several ggplots out of a function for multiplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

Several very similar questions are already discussed here - still I think my problem has not been covered yet:

I want to arrange several ggplots by multiplot.
The ggplots I´m generating in a function:

```
plot_log_means <- function(yname, data, by.list)
```

first aggregating `data$yname` by `by.list` and then plotting by calling ggplot within the function.

When calling the function and printing the plots one by one

```
yname="Krea_1"
p1<-plot_log_means(yname,data=lang_bereinigt, list(lang_bereinigt$cycle, lang_bereinigt$maxi))
p1
yname = "BUN_1"
p2<-plot_log_means(yname,data=lang_bereinigt, list(lang_bereinigt$cycle, lang_bereinigt$maxi))
p2
```

etc

I obtain every single plot as desired.

However, after generating p2, p1 is not accesible any longer:

```
p1
```

produces the well known error:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'BUN_1' not found

although p1 is still present in the list of objects in the workspace.

Thankful for any suggestion!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. The answer to your problem  depends on the structure of your data and your code.

Comment: Found the mistake when preparing the example - a very awkward way to pass the variable to ggplot ggplot(data2, aes(x=jitter(Time), y=eval(parse(text=paste(yname))) ) ... I think I should delete the question to avoid confusion!

Comment: Yes, this happens. Glad to hear that. You can either delete the post or post an answer yourself if you think it will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - ggplot was called within a function

```
plot_log_means <- function(yname, data, by.list)
{ x<-log(data[,yname])
ding <- aggregate(x, by=by.list, FUN=mean )
  names(ding) <- c("Time", "Method", yname)
  ggplot(ding, aes(x=jitter(Time), y=eval(parse(text=paste(yname))), colour=Method)}
```

when passing yname properly to ggplot

```
ggplot(ding, aes(x=jitter(Time), y=ding[,yname], colour=Method))
```

plots can be generated in a for-loop without interfering with each other.